# Оптимизация категоризированного поиска товаров

Tags: php, база-данных

Столкнулся с проблемой скорости загрузки страниц с товарами.
Каждый товар имеет ряд параметров, которые его характеризуют. Параметры, в свою очередь, разбиты по категориям.
Например, товар: цветы имеют параметры «Праздник» – 8 Марта, 14 Февраля… и «Кому подарить»: Маме, Жене, Девушке и т.д.
Пользователь может свободно комбинировать параметры, на основе которых ему показываются подходящие товары. Пытаюсь оптимизировать данную страницу, поскольку время генерации составляет неприличные 10-15 сек:

Подбор товара осуществляется алгоритмом: параметры внутри категории объединяются оператором ИЛИ, сами категории – оператором И. Страница, кроме основного списка, показывает также количество подарков, которое будет получено путем комбинирования уже выбранных и дополнительных параметров. Этот расчет также происходит по тому же алгоритму. Таким образом, мы имеем около 30 таких выборок на каждую загрузку страницы. В большинстве случаев используем подготовленные запросы, но для таких страниц запрос полностью генерируется в php коде вместе с параметрами. Он довольно объемный и плохо оптимизируется с самой базой. Я уже реализовал кэширование (сохраняя результаты всех вычислений для каждой страницы) на стороне сервера.  Так как стоимость товара и его  наличие обновляется, то этот кэш нужно обновлять раз в 1-2 дня. Страниц около 3000, если кэшировать каждую каждый день, то только на кэширование уйдет 10 часов.

Хочу провести сравнительные тесты разных альтернативных алгоритмов. Возможно, у кого-то есть опыт в таких задачах. Буду благодарен за совет.

*Update:*
Ок, кода много, но попытаюсь расписать общую схему:

Структура базы вида:

`products
id, ...`

`properties
id,categoty_id, title`

`products_properties
property_id,categoty_id, product_id`

Пример запроса:

На входе имеем поиск по набору параметров
`1,2,3,4,5,6`

Параметры разбиты по категориям вроде:

`1: {1,4},
2: {2,3,6},
3: {5}`

php-код генерит запрос вида :

```
    SELECT p.*
    FROM products p
    WHERE 1=1
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products_properties ppts WHERE p.id = ppts.product_id AND ppts.property_id IN (1,4)   )
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products_properties ppts WHERE p.id = ppts.product_id AND ppts.property_id IN (2,3,6)   )
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products_properties ppts WHERE p.id = ppts.product_id AND ppts.property_id IN (5)   )
```

Comment: Чем пытаться объяснять на пальцах как примерно выглядит запрос лучше приведите структуру используемых таблиц и запрос на выборку.

Comment: А профилирование пытались провести? У вас может не 30, а 300 таких выборок (кода не видим, поэтому исключать этого нельзя). И как количество подсчитываете? Для этого сортировка не важна, иногда даже join c группировкой не требуются. Т.е. сначала профилирование проведите, если запросов мало, но основное время они съедают - тогда можно и структуру показывать. Если запросов много - надо архитектуру менять. А может и не в запросах дело будет

Comment: Код я ещё свой помню) Количество запросов - 1 в виде сабселекта для центрального блока, и в меню слева каждая циферка - ещё один запрос: [http://begift.com.ua/chto-podarit/](http://begift.com.ua/chto-podarit/)

Если подскажите хороший профилировшик, буду благодарен.

Comment: Для меню слева все кол-ва можно получить одним запросом через группировку. Что-то типа `SELECT name, COUNT(1) AS name_count FROM table GROUP BY name`. Применительно к вашей БД будет чуть сложнее, надо смотреть (пока времени нет). Профилировщиком только одним пользовался (мне хватало): [xhprof](http://ruhighload.com/index.php/2009/08/21/xhprof-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-php-%D0%BE%D1%82-facebook/). Можете попробовать [blackfire](https://blackfire.io/) и поделиться впечатлениями. Либо использовать [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/)

Comment: Структуру таблиц лучше через `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` показывать (выбросив ненужные столбцы). Тогда и индексы видны будут, и тип данных. А вообще про [профилирование запросов](http://debian-help.ru/web-servers/mysql-indexes-explain-profiling/) неплохо бы почитать ([EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) и [SHOW PROFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-profile.html)). Да и сам запрос кривоват )) И общее кол-во, надеюсь через `COUNT()` получаете, а не выбираете все записи, а потом их кол-во в php подсчитываете?

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки, попробую нормальное профилирование) Искать узкие места комментированием кусков кода - довольно муторно)

Comment: Количества, естественно, каунтами, и индексы по полям где выборка тоже есть.

Запрос для mysql действительно кривоват, мне уже обьяснили) насмотрелся я слишком на чуваков, что в таком стиле на Оракле писали)
Проблема в разбитии по категориям - что джоины, что группировки с хевингами нужно писать по-разному для разного числа категорий. В один запрос это можно поместить разве что пользовательскими функциями с "рефлекшенами" внутри

Answer (score 1):

По-моему только проблема с базой данных (неправильно запрос MySql) и проблема с хостингом (скорость хостинга не очень) больше ничего не влияет кроме php код.